# Changes done in ajax success not loading in page without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax block in javascript, which does a few operations, and then changes a text box in my page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/post_to_page/",
    data: JSON.stringify({'titleid': parseInt(count_id)}),
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
    var content_id = "count_" + count_id;
    var votes = $(content_id ).val();
    $(upvotes_id).html(votes);
    //window.location.reload();
    }
    });
```

The content value is reflected only after I refresh the page. I tried setting cache parameter as false and alse the same in ajaxSetup when document is ready. Still the changes arent getting reflected. Please help.

Comment: Please provide all the relevant code. What is inside the variable upvotes_id ? 
Also, arent the "count_" ids instead of tag name ?

Comment: You are taking votes with the wrong way. votes value should be Either $("#content_id").val(); or $(".content_id").val();

I think this "upvotes_id" should be ID ot Class so please try with $("#upvotes_id").html(votes); if class or "$(".upvotes_id").html(votes)" if class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your return variable 'data' isn't being referenced in the success function. As pointed out elsewhere, also missing an id or class reference. Try this (or any other relevant variables):

```
var content_id = "#count_" + data.count_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

add hash to get value like 
var votes = $('#'+content_id ).val();

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot add "#" before the id

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/post_to_page/",
data: JSON.stringify({'titleid': parseInt(count_id)}),
cache: false,
success: function(data){
var content_id = "count_" + count_id;
var votes = $('#'+content_id ).val();   // add hash for id or . for class
$(upvotes_id).html(votes);
//window.location.reload();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming upvotes_id is either id or class. Use $("#upvotes_id").html(votes) or $(".upvotes_id").html(votes) instead.same in the case of "content_id" .

Comment: Yes you are right. That was a small mistake on my part. But after that correction too, the changes are getting reflected only after page reload.

Answer (score 0):

I can see few issues with your code like- no '#' for referring an element.

corrections:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/post_to_page/",
    data: JSON.stringify({'titleid': parseInt(count_id)}),
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
       **var content_id = "#count_" + count_id;**
       var votes = $(content_id ).val();
       $(upvotes_id).html(votes);
       //window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Also you have not mentioned how you are getting `upvotes_id`. Use `#` there too. You are not using the response returned in success method. Is it intended?